# Huge json file and slow loading page

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating weather app with javaScript and i'm using Open Weather Api. Whole application is completed but i'm modfiying it for my own needs. I made input to enter a city and now im trying to add some hints for the input, so when user type in "Lond" under input there are  showing up all cities with "Lond" in its name for example: London, Londonderry etc. I downloaded a city list from openweatherapi page but the json file with all cities is about 40MB. The file is so big that when i type in "lond" into input i have to wait about few seconds until the cities show up. And there is my question. Is there a way to speed up the search procedure.

Comment: Please add more details as to how you're using this city list in your app. Meaning how it's included and how you're searching it.

Comment: Normally, you would do this matching server-side.  Is this a possibility for you?  If not, you could do some really hacky stuff by segmenting a JSON file, but this is going to take thousands and thousands of files and a script to generate them.

Comment: How can we know if there's a way to speed up something we can't see. Try adding some code.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a question for SO. But I suppose one thing you could do is the classic async autocomplete: query a third-party API upon keystroke (ideally with a debounce) and then display the results to the user instead of storing some huge list of cities locally.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use a third party API or library(if there is any)

---

But if you want to stick to the file you downloaded and want to use that, then:

Maybe you just make an object with multiple arrays, each starting letter gets its own array.

obj = {a: [], b:[], ...}
Once you write down the first letter, you just start filtering the specific array?

obj['a'] = obj.a

Comment: I don't think that will help reduce file size. But it may help performance, especially if you keep splitting things into objects as you go further down the strings, which should result in a tree. I think that's a common search-optimization technique but I'm blanking on the name.